# Loading .js file in UIWebview from bundle downloaded as a zip

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, bundle

I want to show a "complete website" (which is packaged in a bundle) in an UIWebView.

When I put the bundle in xcode and adding it to "compile stuff", everything is perfectly loaded, the js files works fine.

Unfortunately, to permit to update this website, I need this one to be downloaded as a zip from another server...
I can easily get the zip, extract it and put everything in a bundle BUT when I load the index page in the UIWebView, the js files aren't working !

How can I set anything to make this code executable or something like that ?

Here is the part to load my bundle created :

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *test = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:documentsDirectory] pathForResource:@"contentNewVersion.bundle/index" ofType:@"html"];

[_webView  loadRequest:[NSURLRequest  requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:test isDirectory:NO]]];
```

The location of my index is : /var/mobile/Applications/A2B602C3-DEC0-40FE-9469-288F666196A7/Documents/contentNewVersion.bundle/index.html `

Comment: can you please put you code regarding this, what you are doing exactly.. so that we can help you..

Answer (score 1):

// Try this

```
 NSString *test = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/contentNewVersion.bundle/index.html"];

NSLog(@"%@",test);

[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:test]]];
```

Comment: /contentNewVersion.bundle/index.html   if this path is always constant this will help full for you

Comment: Same problem, js is not executed :(

Comment: you are trying to load .js or html? if js, please give this path(/contentNewVersion.bundle/index.js) in obove line of code

Comment: in NSDocumentDirectory you are creating any folder to save js file?

Comment: I want to load contentNewVersion.bundle/index.html (which is well load for the html part)

All my files are coming from zip file and the js files are in the root of the bundle, next to index.html

Answer (score 1):

// Below Block of code is the procedure to load js file in UIWebview from NSDocumentDirectory

```
 NSString *JSFilePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myfile.js"];

NSString *str_JSFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<script src='%@'></script>", JSFilePath];

    [webview loadHTMLString:str_JSFilePath baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
```

Comment: You mean I need to load manually all my js files before loading the html in my webview ?

Comment: what your js file is going to returning, once js file is loaded in web view?

Comment: They are just containing function to be used in the html file ! (jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js and stuff like that...)

Comment: But I'm already doing what you gave me in the html file : 
 <script src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
 <script src="global.js"></script>